# pygments ScssLexer issues warning when scss variables are used

Tags: sass, python-sphinx, pygments

I'm using sphinx with the ScssLexer `class pygments.lexers.css.ScssLexer`.

When I try to include a `.. code-block: scss` in an `.rst` file that uses variables, such as:

```
.. code-block:: scss

  h1 {
    color: $blue;
  }
```

I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Could not lex literal_block as "scss". Highlighting skipped.
```

The variables are defined in an scss file that is meant to be included in the code by the reader of the docs.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Here's a bug report https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1096/scss-variable-not-detected-in-attribute

Comment: Also including reference to Plone Training Docs: https://github.com/plone/training/pull/285#issuecomment-335030718